# Why sometimes the create operation cannot trigger the on create trigger in progress?

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl, 4gl

This code is executed first in the project
ON CREATE OF customer
DO:
...
END.
And the code of "CREATE customer." is executed elsewhere in the project, but it does not trigger the code in "ON CREATE".

Answer (score 2):

Make sure, that the code executing the ON CREATE OF ... is in the call stack of the code that does the CREATE.

If for instance your startup procedure runs an "init" procedure that does the ON CREATE OF ... and then runs an application window that performs the CREATE, the trigger is no longer valid.

In case of doubt, define the trigger block in the startup procedure directly.